# setting vertical scroll bar of scrollviewer to be visible

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visibility, scrollviewer

i am trying to set the verticalscrollbar visibility to be visible during a button click event. Why can't i do something like this?

before click event, XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Height="178.75" Width="680" Name="Scroller">
```

button click event in C#:

```
Scroller.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Answer (score 1):

-.-

It's the wrong enumeration:

```
Scroller.VerticalScrollBarVisibility =  ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
```

You should really check the [types of properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.verticalscrollbarvisibility.aspx) before assigning random stuff to it.